# React gradient slider (rating component) with rounded corners

Tags: css, reactjs, slider, gradient

I'm quite new in CSS and React.
My task is to make a component like on the image below.

[image]

This is what I have made by covering gradient div with white color and opacity like 0.2. Color doesn't matter.

[image]

Can you help me to make a rounded border inside a slider like on a first image?

[image]

Adding missing code. 
I've modified Benjamin's Reid example.

Here's my code:

```js
class MySlider extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      rating: this.props.rating || null,
      tempRating: null
    };
  }

  rate = (rating) => {
    this.setState({
      rating,
      tempRating: rating
    });
  };

  starOver = (rating) => {
    this.setState({
      rating,
      tempRating: this.state.rating
    });
  };

  starOut = () => {
    this.setState({
      rating: this.state.tempRating
    });
  };

  render() {
    const elements = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      let cssSelectorClass = 'my-slider__item';

      if (this.state.rating !== null && this.state.rating >= i) {
        cssSelectorClass += ' --selected';
      }

      elements.push(
        <div
          className={cssSelectorClass}
          onClick={this.rate.bind(this, i)}
          onMouseOver={this.starOver.bind(this, i)}
          onMouseOut={this.starOut} />
      );
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="back" />
        <div className="my-slider">
          {elements}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <MySlider value={2} />
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.my-slider {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.my-slider__item {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.my-slider__item:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
    }

.--selected {
      opacity: 0;
}

.back {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, blue, red);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #00ccff;
  border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'></div>
```

en/vNVwPW

Comment: Could you please also share some code? Some basic idea without seeing any code --> the height of your bar is 50px (as an example), so you can apply `border-top-right-radius: 25px;` and  `border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;` to it to make it rounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the code it's hard to answer, especially because we don't know how your Component is built.
Anyways, I just "tried and guest": let me know if this helps you:

```js
class ProgressBar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="progressBar">
                <div
                    className="currentProgress"
                    style={{width: `calc(${this.props.value}%)`}}/>
            </div>            
        );
    }
}

class App extends React.Component {
    interval;
    
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        
        this.state = {value: 75};
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
        this.interval = setInterval(() => {
            this.setState({ value: Math.floor(Math.random() * (75-65+ 1) + 65)});
        }, 500)
    }
    
    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    }
    
    render() {
        return <ProgressBar value={this.state.value} />
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

body {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.progressBar {
    width: 500px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #FDE9EC;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
}

.currentProgress {
    height: inherit;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #33ccff 0%, #ff99cc 100%);;
    border-top-right-radius: inherit;
    border-bottom-right-radius: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'></div>
```

As you can see, it's pretty easy: `ProgressBar` Component renders two `div`s. The first one is the progress bar, while the inner `div` is the current progress, given by a value passed as `props`.
For the border, since the we have parent/child hierarchy, we can use `inherit` CSS value.

Comment: The cool thing is that You nested div with background and gradient instead of using z-index. Also modifying style in React component which allows manipulating the element width in runtime. This information will help me to build my own component in a totally different way. Ps. I am building a kind of rating component, no progress bar :).

Comment: I gave my answer when there was no code of yours, so I just implemented the way I came up with, I'm glad it can be helpful :)
You may find also helpful `styled-components` package: it allows you write CSS in JS, giving you lots of power

Comment: I heard about that, but it's not good practice in my company. The opinion is that CSS in JS is slowing down web pages so we are using SCSS instead. The styles you showed me give me enough power to move on. Thanks, Jolly.

Comment: Ok :) Two more things: (1) look into compatibility of my solution with all browsers (maybe IE and Edge may need some adjustments). (2) If you think your rating component will move like in my example, you could find useful the `react-move` package, with which you can achieve smooth movement using animation